# How do I convert a SQL query to rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm new to ROR. The query I created below is functioning properly. I'm trying to prepare an interrogation. But I didn't succeed. The query is as follows;

```
@rad_user_group.groupname = SELECT groupname FROM radgrs INNER JOIN nas WHERE radgrs.grdefault = true AND radgrs.tenant_id = nas.tenant_id AND nas.realipaddr = "192.168.22.175" AND nas.active = true
```

How do I make a switch case for the following queries in another question? Returns NULL if the query fails.

Thank you for caring.

```
def realipaddr
    request.remote_addr
  end

  def create
    @rad_check = RadCheck.new(rad_check_params)
    @rad_check.tenant_id = Na.find_by(realipaddr: realipaddr, active: :true).tenant_id

    respond_to do |format|
      if @rad_check.save
        format.html { redirect_to @rad_check, notice: 'Rad check was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @rad_check }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @rad_check.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

**RadCheck Model**

```
class RadCheck < ApplicationRecord
    has_one :rad_user_group, dependent: :destroy

    after_initialize :add_rad_user_group
    before_save :set_radcheck   

    def add_rad_user_group
      self.rad_user_group ||= RadUserGroup.new if self.new_record?
    end

    def set_radcheck
      self.rad_user_group.username = username
      self.op = ":="
      self.attribu = "Cleartext-Password"
    end 
end

class CreateRadChecks < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :rad_checks do |t|
      t.integer :tenant_id
      t.string :username
      t.string :password
      t.string :attribu
      t.string :op
      t.string :realipaddr
      t.string :groupname

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

**Radgr Model**

```
class Radgr < ApplicationRecord
end

class CreateRadgrs < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :radgrs do |t|
      t.integer :tenant_id
      t.string :groupname
      t.string :realipaddr
      t.boolean :grdefault

    end
  end
end
```

**RadUserGroup Model**

```
class RadUserGroup < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :rad_check
end

class CreateRadUserGroups < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :rad_user_groups do |t|
      t.integer :tenant_id
      t.string :username
      t.string :groupname
      t.references :rad_check, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

**Na Model**

```
class Na < ApplicationRecord
end

class CreateNas < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :nas do |t|
      t.integer :tenant_id
      t.string :nasname
      t.string :realipaddr
      t.boolean :active

    end
  end
end
```

[PhpMyAdmin Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9czT3.png)

Comment: What are your models and assocaitions? you original query is returning a set of records and you are assgning that to an id, it looks like you are missing something like "LIMIT 1" or getting only the first. With proper associations you could do something like: `Radgrs.joins(:nas).where(nas: {realipaddr: '1292...'}).first` but I'm just guessing, you didn't show your models.

Answer (score 0):

You should better organize the object associations. The objects obviously having some sort of relations.
Like Radgr model and Na model. I think you can make relation between these two, so later you can use query command `all  = Radgr.includes(:nas).where("nas.realipaddr =?", "192.168.22.175")` or something similar.

Also here is a good site for converting SQL to ActiveRecord query,  but you need here to create your models and associations for testing. 
Please check:
http://www.scuttle.io/

Comment: I've looked at this site before. But I couldn't get out of it. The SQL query above is exactly what I want. I added the models and tables to the topic.

Comment: How do you think the relationship between Radgr and Na models should be... rails g migration CreateJoinTableRadgrNa radgr na.... I wonder if I should create a migration like